# Некорректная кодировка таблицы MySQL / некорректная настройка MyWebInitializer.java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

Изучаю Spring.
Написал простое CRUD приложение с использованием Spring, MySQL и Hibernate.

Кириллица - сохраняется некорректно. Знатоки Spring и Hibernate, не оставьте без внимания, пожалуйста.

[image: Иван Петров]

*Настройки БД (Пробовал менять на `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`) не помогло.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Таблица `employees`*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Структура проекта*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файлы:

```
MyConfig

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/view/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/view/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/view/img/");
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_utf8_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC");
            dataSource.setUser("bestuser");
            dataSource.setPassword("bestuser");
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.entity");

        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);

        return sessionFactory;

    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

*`MyWebInitializer`* (пробовал добавлять javax.servlet.Filter
и org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
но к сожалению не помогло.)

```
package com.example.configuration;

import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

public class MyWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

//    @Override
//    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
//        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
//        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
//        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
//        return new Filter[]{filter};
//    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{MyConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

*`Web.xml`* (Так же пробовал добавлять `characterEncodingFilter` и так же без результата)

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<!--  <filter>-->
<!--    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>-->
<!--    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>-->
<!--    <init-param>-->
<!--      <param-name>encoding</param-name>-->
<!--      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>-->
<!--    </init-param>-->
<!--    <init-param>-->
<!--      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>-->
<!--      <param-value>true</param-value>-->
<!--    </init-param>-->
<!--  </filter>-->

<!--  <filter-mapping>-->
<!--    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>-->
<!--    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>-->
<!--  </filter-mapping>-->

</web-app>

*view*
```

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Employee info</h2>
<br>
<form:form action="/saveEmployee" modelAttribute="employee">
    <form:hidden path="id"/>

    Name <form:input path="name"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    Surname <form:input path="surname"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="ОК">

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

*`pom.xml`*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-UTF8</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>test-UTF8 Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.28.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.23</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.1</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>test-UTF8</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

*SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *Настройки БД* Мало. Показывайте результат выполнения `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'; SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';`.

Comment: @Akina


| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                                        
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4
| character_set_filesystem | binary
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4
| character_set_system     | utf8
| character_sets_dir           | /C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\

Comment: Добавьте в текст вопроса с форматированием, а не комментарием.

Comment: при подключении указывайте кодировку view_db?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf8

Comment: @lampa указал Ваш вариант. получаю эксепшн org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

Comment: @МаксимЯкушев там должна быть еще ниже ошибка,  т.к. эта ошибка не раскрывает причину

Comment: У меня есть проект в котором настройка идет через applicationContext.xml. В этом проекте в  файле web.xml указана в теге <filter> кодировка.  Там кириллица работает корректно. У меня в коде этот кусок закомментирован. Посмотрите выше....  Я пробую указать данную информацию  в MyWebInitializer.java. остальные настройки и у меня одинаковые в двух проектах. у меня не получается корректно прописать именно web.xml и/или MyWebInitializer.java